# How to do table like format without tables

Tags: html

I'm trying to set up a website to display a twitch channel. For this, I embedded the channel, and the chat. I also put the logo. However, because the chat reaches down farther than the player, the logo can't go directly below the player. I know you could allow the logo to go below with tables, but those are a big headache, so I was wondering if there was another way to put the logo directly below the player. Website: https://katamonia--449243.repl.co/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Katamonia</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#333">
<center>
<iframe align="top" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=katamonia" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" height="582" width=74%>
<iframe frameborder="2"
scrolling="no"
src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/katamonia/chat"
height="100"
width="100">
</iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/katamonia/chat?darkpopout" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" height="758" width=24%></iframe>
</center>
</br>
<img align="top" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/778094/2.0" height="200" width="200">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would benefit from using CSS. HTML alone will only be rendered in the order it is written. Also, do a little research on the HTML you choose you have at least one obsolete/deprecated tag in there (<center>). Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Obsolete_and_deprecated_elements

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that obsolete tag. What CSS would I need to know for this though?

Comment: There are so many different approaches... Yours is a question with too many answers. Start researching: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction

Answer (score 0):

So you forgot to close the first `<iframe>` tag with `</iframe>`. Then you can wrap different contents with `<div></div>` containers to create a clear structure and add proper alignment. I made a fiddle for you that shows you how you could do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/NicolasDurant/xp9wf8t6/

It also would be great, if you can extract your stylings out of your HTML file into a seperate CSS file, so you have all the stylings in one place.

There are alot of possibilities to align containers. I used flexbox. Here is a complete guide about that: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

One of the most used libraries for arrangement and default components is bootstrap, you should give it a try:
https://getbootstrap.com/